# MVC - Implement members online functionality

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app and I want to add
to each page a list of members online. Actually add to Master page.

Members belong to groups so I want to
show all members in there groups.

So what is the best way of doing this??

Eg On session start add to a collection that is in cache object
and remove it on session end in Global.asax.

Is that a reliable way??
Traffic wont be enormous.

Malcolm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How can I determine the number of users on an ASP.NET site (IIS)? And their info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155593/how-can-i-determine-the-number-of-users-on-an-asp-net-site-iis-and-their-info) The same approach can be used for WebForms as well as ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll have to use the Application object to store it, 
and you could do it in the Session Start/Session End events. 
Add to the Application on Start, and remove on End.