# How to find how many users are browsing your webpage at the same time?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to find using asp.net,

How many users are browsing my website at any particular instance of time.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an application variable and increment it during *Session_Start* in the Global.asax. Also this variable needs to be decremented when the *Session_End* event is fired.

Comment: This link could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155593/how-can-i-determine-the-number-of-users-on-an-asp-net-site-iis-and-their-info

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using the ASP.NET Membership Provider -  [Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getnumberofusersonline.aspx)
2. Or you could try one of the [ASP.NET performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx). 
   **State Server Sessions Active**
   The number of currently active user sessions. This counter is available only on the computer where the state server service (aspnet_state) is running.