# One web page, two authenticated users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I apologize in advance for not including any code in this one as the question is so unusual I was unable to find any decent information about it and I have a hard time wrapping my head around it as well. I also apologize if the question displays such a ludicrous lack of understanding on my part, that you sprained something laughing...

Imagine, if you will, a "multiplayer" web page. There's a login page, user can log in, his or her name gets displayed somewhere, cookie is set. So far, no rocket science.

Now let's take it a little further: once the user is logged in, a SECOND user should be able to log in and his or her username should be displayed as well, on the other half of the page, let's say.

Let's assume for a moment that they each get a half page to work with, that way you have a visual idea of what that would be like. It's like opening two text editors next to each other, let's say.

So... how do I approach this? Do I write a proverbial

```
ApplicationSignInManager.MultiSignIn(ApplicationUser user)
```

then another

```
AuthenticationManager.SignIn
```

and just rewrite the whole shebang beneath it until I get a cookie with two users in it? Is it really that straightforward? (I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 by the way)

Or is my understanding so lacking that I shouldn't even consider this?

The thing is: the use case *is* there. I *need* to build it, any which way. I just can't figure out how to approach it... can you?

**EDIT:**

- There will always be a finite number of people interacting with this web page. Let's assume, for the moment, a maximum of 2.
- YES, these two people will be on the SAME computer, each interacting with only their OWN half of the screen.

Comment: So are you saying that 2 people will log in on the same client computer?

Comment: @NightOwl888 Exactly! The page is split in half. I get left, you get right. We both log in.

Comment: Take a look at this page: http://ruchirac.blogspot.com.ar/2013/02/basics-of-creating-multiplayer-web.html What you need is SignalR which is built for this kind of realtime stuff.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo I have no need for SignalR as the page will not need to reflect remote changes in realtime. It's one page on one physical computer with two people.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about a few core concepts when it comes to web programming.

I will assume that the *second user* is not on the same computer as the *first user*.

Multiple users can of course be logged in with the default `FormsAuthentication` that comes with `ASP.NET`. A cookie would not solve *anything* since the cookie is "per user".

This is a somewhat complicated matter, because what you are describing would require a pretty intimate client/server relationship.

I assume that you want to be notified of when a user has logged on; when another use *has logged on* and not on the next page reload. This would require some sort of *web service* or at least a few ajax-requests.

The first step (however) would be to "flag" the user that has logged on as `online`, and when the user logs of, flag the user as `not-online` this way you can fetch the online users at all times via a web request. The way you decide to store your users does not matter; just make sure you can flag them as `online`/`not-online`.

The easiest way to get the online users would be via ajax.
Using jQuery:

```
$.get('users/OnlineList', function (data) { 
    // Let's just assume that "data" is just a comma-separated string of users.
    $('div#online-users').text(data);
});
```

Then do that every x seconds, via `setInterval` or similar. This is hacky and ugly, but it works; and it is how many people do it.

---

But back to the problem at hand.

The way i see it; the best way to do this (if it's always two people). Is to have some sort of "lobby"-system, when `User-A` logs in, `User-A` is put in `Lobby-1`. When `User-B` logs in, this user is also put in `Lobby-1`, and `Lobby-1` is now closed, no more people can join. `User-C` and `User-D` is put in `Lobby-2` and so on.

So in conclusion:

- You have a cool idea, but you are approaching it the wrong way.
- You need to store the users in some sort of database, with an offline/online flag
- You need to poll the database now and then to see what users are online
- You will need to develop some sort of *lobby* system for the users if you want more than two users be able to use your service simultaneously.
- You need to touch up on the basics on web programming

I hope my answer has been of some help!

Comment: thanks for your insights. I'm sure they'll help me piece together a viable solution. I've updated my question to reflect what I apparently forgot to mention. Be sure to read up on that. The users are NOT on different computers!

Answer (score 0):

The webpage should check on the webserver/database if a second user is logged in and do something (displaying the username). If you need further infos, let me know.

Let's say you have a login page and after a successful login it updates a record in the table "user" in column "loggedin" to "true". Let's say you have on the main page a ticker, that shows all logged in users. If you navigate to the main page, the page select all users with column "loggedin" = "true and count it. The result is saved in a variable and displayed on the site.

If you want to know something, from different users you have to save it on a database or a "static" variable.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate and explain it in a little more detail.

Comment: so you're saying this can't be solved using one or more cookies?

Comment: Maybe like that:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155593/how-can-i-determine-the-number-of-users-on-an-asp-net-site-iis-and-their-info